# Euro symbol in PHP ereg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I want to allow the euro symbol € in this regex but it wont come through

```
$val = ereg_replace($regex, "[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:][:blank:]€+-]+", $_REQUEST[$var]);
```

Comment: ereg does not support unicode natively I think. Time to use preg_replace, ereg_* hasn't been recommended to use since the winter of '74.

Comment: Fair enough what am I doing wrong here  $val = preg_replace([^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:][:blank:]€+-]+", "", $_REQUEST[$var]);

Comment: Missing " right after preg_replace( and also the delimiters / as @M42 answered above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment, you've forgotten the delimiters required by preg_replace:

```
$string = 'ab!:;c+12,.3 €def-x/';
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s€+-]+/', '', $string);
echo $string,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
abc+123 €def-x
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you have mbstring instaled? If so, try using the function [mb_ereg_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php). It'll support this caracter (even in UTF-8).

Edit: Also check if mbregex is on. Some hosts turn mbstring on but disables mbregex (I don't know why).

Comment: While trying some options to suggest for you, just fixing the errors in your regex worked for me here (using preg_replace).

Answer (score 1):

Check that the charset used by your text editor / IDE is **iso-8859-15** (if this is why you are trying to display).

If it's **UTF-8**, you will have to do another replace especially for it (`€` being represented on several bytes, I guess that it won't fit into a `[...]` regex block).

BTW, [`ereg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php) has been deprecated in favor of [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Plus, why do you have two "regex" parameters? (I suppose that `$regex` contains a regex too?)

Suggestion (untested), if what you want to do is remove € + other chars in your initial regex:

```
$val = preg_replace(
    array('/[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:][:blank:]+\-]+/', '/€/'),
    '',
    $_REQUEST[$var]
  );
```

Comment: preg needs to start and end with the same delimiter.

Comment: This will replace the euro symbol `€` by nothing.